# Can we Find if the app is installed in the mobile at Client side(mobile browser) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

Is there any way to check the at the client side (mobile web browser) wheather app is installed in mobile or not

Comment: @psyLogic that link has nothing to do with the OP's question

Answer (score 0):

For obvious privacy reasons this is not possible.

Comment: thanks for the immediate reply @incompleteness